# How to compare two lists and find the mismatch them in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two list namely, list1 and list2

Suppose if my list1 has the following elements,

```
"first", "second","third"
```

and my list2 has the following elements,

```
"element first is present here"
"elements are present in second"
```

So in this case, the string "first" and "second" are present in the list2.(but not exactly the same as in variablelist).

So in this case, how can I except "first" and "second" and show my result as, only "third" element is not present in the list2?

I am using the following code

```
var inOnlyVariableList = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: And what fails about your code?

Comment: use version with equality comparer: [Enumerable.Except<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @BugFinder the query returns me all the elements from list1. But i want only`"third"` to get stored in `inOnlyVariableList` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a set based approach(like `Except`) if you search substrings. So it's not as efficient but still readable:

```
var inOnlyVariableList = list1.Where(s => !list2.Any(s2 => s2.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

`String.Contains` looks if the given string is contained in the larger string.

If you want to support case insensitive comparison you can use:

```
var inOnlyVariableList = list1
    .Where(s => list2.All(s2 => s2.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1))
    .ToList();
```